# Couple a function inside mutate dplyr r: Calculate second derivative

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the following formula on all my data `grouped_by(id)`

```
$$\frac{y''}{((1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}$$
```

I'm getting stuck on passing a function through mutate because it gives me unequal column sizes.

**Sample data is:**

```
require(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(Time=seq(65),
               SkinTemp=rnorm(65,37,0.5),
               id=rep(1:10,c(5,4,10,6,7,8,9,8,4,4)))
```

**First derivative (OK):**

```
df <-df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(first_d = SkinTemp - lag(SkinTemp))
df<-as.data.frame(df)  #Back to data frame
```

**Second derivative (stuck):**

```
drv <- function(x, y) diff(y) / diff(x) #Defined this to pass to mutate

middle_pts <- function(x) x[-1] - diff(x) / 2 

second_d <-df %>% group_by(id)  %>%
  mutate(second_d = drv(middle_pts(Time), drv(Time, SkinTemp)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `diff` returns a vector of length one less than the original `vector`.  The function `mutate` requires the column to return the same length.  Therefore, we need to do some appending with `NA` or value of choice

```
drv <- function(x, y) c(NA, (diff(y) /diff(x))) 
middle_pts <- function(x) c(NA, (x[-1] - diff(x) /2))
```

Now, the OP's code should work

```
df %>%
   group_by(id)  %>%
   mutate(second_d = drv(middle_pts(Time), drv(Time, SkinTemp)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you think there's a clever way of dealing with the NANs? I'm trying to find the max second_d for each id.

Comment: @HCAI After I updated the function, I couldn't find any NaN's

Comment: I believe the first two entries under the second_id column for each id will be NaN. I've used aggregate to get ignore them while finding max so should be ok now. Thank you.

Comment: @HCAI  It may be due to the seed.